# Heroku Node App error "no such file or directory" on logout

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

The app was working completely until deployment on heroku. There everything works fine (including login) except for the logout button which returns a 404 Not Found status code.

and in the heroku logs:

heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logout" host=xxxxxxx request_id=4596d3a6-5b4b-4c29-846f-de5b80e718e0 fwd="178.248.111.38" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=412 protocol=https
2020-07-02T21:26:49.990193+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/build/logout'

here is the code from app.js in the server:

```
app.get('/:route', (req, res) => {
  const route = req.params.route;
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', route));
});

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  registerUser(req, res);
});

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  loginUser(req, res);
});

app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  logoutUser(req, res);
});
```

what could cause this issue? the login route has the exact same path but with "login" instead of "logout" so why would one work but not the other?

Comment: maybe method is wong, shouldn't it be POST instead of GET ?

Comment: but in the app.js in the server its defined as a GET method

Comment: Well, looks like your first `app.get('/:route', (req, res) => {` handler handles GET to /logout this case. You should either put `app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {` on the first place (not sure if this is how express works), or make it POST.

Comment: you're right - i made a mistake. i just changed it and now it works -    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});